# Alexa Sites Linking In

Tags: alexa

I have read that Alexa updates its "Sites Linking In" only once per month (although ranking is updated daily, as I monitor it daily).

Are there any webmasters here who track "Sites Linking In" and know how often it is updated by Alexa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Alexa for two of my websites. I have observed that Alexa Traffic Rank is updated on a daily basis, just as you described. That is consistent with the **[Alexa Traffic detail page](http://www.alexa.com/help/traffic-learn-more)**.

Regarding "Sites Linking In", I have not observed the number changing very often. **[Alexa FAQ](http://www.alexa.com/faqs/?p=91)** says that it is only updated once per month:

> We update the number of sites linking in only once per month for all
>   sites.

The only way to get daily updates of sites linking is if you pay for an **[extra Alexa service](http://www.alexa.com/faqs/?cat=221)**:

> The links-in count for sites with an **Enhanced Site Listing** is updated **daily instead of monthly**.

All three of the fee-based Alexa plans include Enhanced Site Listing functionality, with daily updates.

Comment: Yes, Alexa only update once a month but you can get daily updates if you buy their Alexa Pro Package.

Comment: @DidYouKnow Yes, that is what I was referring to in my answer. It is called Enhanced Site Listing. Alexa has three different fee-based or "Pro Packages". Enhanced Site Listing is bundled with each of them, and as mentioned above, shows daily updates.

Comment: I have not seen any changes in back links of Alexa. Is there any other trustable website like Alexa to shows links?

Answer (score 0):

Altho they are updating once a month But i found them very inaccurate. I have way more sites linking in, and it still in growing but alexa has lower than 20 links...